# Como gerar o hash SHA-1

Tags: firebase, sha1

Estou configurando o meu projeto para implementar o login com o Google, porem estou tendo algumas dificuldades ele pede a chave SHA-1, e não sei quais comandos deve utilizar para gerar a chave.

O Google passa este comando mas preciso saber o que inserir nele:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

Answer (score 0):

O google está pedindo o caminho para sua chave de debug. No meu notebook utilizo:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\meuNome\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```